# Hadoop: method setMapperClass in class JobConf cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, hadoop

I am very new to using the Hadoop framework in Java.  I am trying to set the `JobConf` for a particular map reduce job that only has a mapper (no real intermediate values for a reducer).  My mapper class is here:

```
public static class GetArticlesMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, WikipediaPage, Text, Text> 
{
    public static Set<String> peopleArticlesTitles = new HashSet<String>();

    @Override
    protected void setup(Mapper<LongWritable, WikipediaPage, Text, Text>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO: You should implement people articles load from
        // DistributedCache here
        super.setup(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable offset, WikipediaPage inputPage, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO: You should implement getting article mapper here
    }
}
```

However, this line in the main method throws an error when I compile the java file:

```
conf.setMapperClass(GetArticlesMapper.class);
```

which says:

> error: method setMapperClass in class JobConf cannot be applied to
>   given types;
>         conf.setMapperClass(GetArticlesMapper.class);
>             ^   required: Class   found: Class   reason: actual argument
>   Class cannot be converted to Class by method invocation conversion 1 error

Thus my question is, what do I need to fix in my implementation of the mapper class so Java compiles and I do not get this error?  This question might be poorly worded and vague, perhaps because of my own unfamiliarity with this subject.  I would appreciate any comments to help improve the quality of this question as well.

Comment: JobConf is old API and your displayed code is new API.You can move forward using any of one.Donot mix both. You can find example of wordcount using new API here: http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/hadoop-wordcount-example-in-detail.html

Answer (score 5):

You are probably mixing the "old API" and the "new API". Basicly the old API (which JobConf is a part of) lives under `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` and the new API (which use Job and Configuration instead) lives under `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce`. Your mapped is probably implementing `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper`.

More details on all the differences can be found here: http://hadoopbeforestarting.blogspot.de/2012/12/difference-between-hadoop-old-api-and.html.

Comment: That is unfortunate.  The fully fleshed MapReduce example [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html) uses the old api then?  Do you know where I could find an example that uses the new API (source code, not just the jar).

Comment: A quick google somes up with this page: http://codesfusion.blogspot.sg/2013/10/hadoop-wordcount-with-new-map-reduce-api.html which seems to be the correct new API use. It is indeed very annoying that most of the examples out there use the old API - I've battled with this many times :)